# Anthy uses previously selected (wrong) layout

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, japanese

Using Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I have the following input sources in Text Entry: Russian, Japanese (Anthy), English (US).

When switching to "Japanese (Anthy)" from "English (US)", everything works fine. But when switching from "Russian", the keyboard layout remains Russian and consequently I can't type anything in Japanese (since Anthy converts from Latin letters).

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround for this? Googling doesn't yield anything sensible.

Comment: Russian, Japanese AND English?  Upvoted both Q&A!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting the question I found this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1311990

Unfortunately the reporter was content with a workaround and changed the status to invalid.

The workaround is to change "Keyboard layout" under "Typing Method" to something other than "Default".